# How to change background color of TextView and EditText in xml

Tags: android, xml, background, textview, android-edittext

This is my code:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"
                android:layout_column="1"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_column="2"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

How can I set background of TextView to green and background of EditText to red?

EDIT:

I want to change color of the whole cell like in HTML td tag. When I set background attribute of edittext it changes its inner color but I want to change color around it.

EDIT 2:

I changed my code to what Hamid Shatu suggested:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TableRow
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="#00FF00"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"
                android:layout_column="1"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_column="2"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="#00FF00"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"
                android:layout_column="1"/>
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText3" android:layout_column="2"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

and now it looks almost entirely as I wanted except there is now red line over TextView. How can I get rid of this line?

Comment: there are many example are available on google

Comment: Show me one example that answers my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `android:background` xml attribute for both `TextView` and `EditText` to change their background color...

```
android:background="#color_code"
```

as follows...

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:background="#0000FF" />
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:background="#00FF00" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Update:** then change the `TableRow`'s background color and `EditText`s backgroung color so that it changes the around color of `EditText`.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0000FF" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: It is not exacltly wat I wanted. TextView background is ok. I edited my question.

Comment: Now it is almost perfect. There is only one thing. I edited my post second time.

Comment: Change the `android:background` of `TextView`.

Comment: I get your **solution**: add `android:layout_margin="0dip"` to your `EditText` xml attributs...you will your problem fixed.

Comment: I added it but it didn't change anything

Comment: Which API do you use?

Comment: Sorry, in my real device I'm getting the same problem as like you. I'm checking why its happening.

Answer (score 2):

inside textview

```
android:background="#FF0000"
```

in edittext

```
android:background="#00B800"
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

> ```
>           <TextView
>             android:layout_width="0dp"
>             android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
>             android:layout_weight=".50"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:padding="10dp"
>             android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing andtypesetting"
>             android:layout_column="1"/>
> ```

But you should use colors that you define in your file for example: colors.xml

Comment: This one gives me "Cannot resolve symbol '@android:color/holo_green_dark'"

Comment: This sample require API at least 14.

Comment: This does not answer my question. There is EditText part missing in your answer.

Comment: Bartek... just use in edit text background property ... if you really do not need to use defined by you colors next time look at defined colors in android. Like I put in sample.         This is your red color: android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"

Comment: But I don't want to change inner background of EditText. I want to change background around EditText. See my question, I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:background="#FF0000"` for red and `android:background="#00FF00"` for green

Answer (score 0):

Include `android:background= "color-code"` inside your textview and edittext.